# Add row to a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 4 columns as follows:

```
nb,state,freebk,freebs
901,1,6,14
903,0,2,18
904,1,10,20
905,1,15,5
```

I want to add all the rows that have state equal to 1 to a new dataframe

Desired new dataframe:

```
nb,state,freebk,freebs
    901,1,6,14
    904,1,10,20
    905,1,15,5
```

I tried the following

```
 openStationDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nb','state','freebk','freebs'])
    t = 0
    for i in range(len(stationDF)):
        station = stationDF.iloc[i]
        if station[0] == 1:
            openStationDF.loc[t] = station
            t = t + 1
```

This code added successfully the stations with state = 1 but what is happing is that the nb of the station is = NaN and the Name of the station started from 0 and then incrementing by one.

```
nb         NaN
state      1.0
freebk     6.0
freebs    14.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
nb         NaN
state      1.0
freebk    10.0
freebs    20.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
nb         NaN
state      1.0
freebk    15.0
freebs     5.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

I want the name to equal the nb of the station(name = 901...)

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query#pandas-dataframe-query):

```
df_new = df.query('state == 1')
```

Or, use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_new = df[df['state'] == 1]
```

Output:

```
    nb  state  freebk  freebs
0  901      1       6      14
2  904      1      10      20
3  905      1      15       5
```

Comment: would you have a pointer to the pros and cons of querying vs boolean indexing?

Comment: I like query for readability, but boolean indexing can be faster depending on data.